# How to make Unity Dash full screen?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

When you hit the `Windows` key on the keyboard the dash opens:

[image: like this image]

But I am using a 20" monitor and the launcher is smaller.

Is it possible to make the Unity dash full screen? like the Gnome launcher?

Comment: It's called the Dash. The Unity launcher is the column of icons to the left.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, just use the Maximize button.

Comment: so obvious but for some reason I just didn't see it there